# Remote debugging google app engine and vagrant

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, vagrant

I am new to Vagrant. I have GAE project with a vagrantfile and right after doing vagrant up I am able to access `localhost:8080` (as the port is forwarded).

1)How google app engine started running? I didn't ssh into vagrant and didn't started the project. How is this configured?

2) As I don't have `GAE dev_appserver.py` running on terminal. Where I can see the print log?